# Command line to remove oldest backup

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, automation, backup

I am having the following directory with multiple `Backup from $(date +"%d.%m.%Y at %H:%M:%S").zip` files.

```
/opt/
   /opt/files/
      /opt/files/private/*
      /opt/files/backup.sh
      /opt/files/backup.txt
      /opt/files/Backup from $(date +"%d.%m.%Y at %H:%M:%S").zip
```

With a daily cronjob `0 0 * * * cd /opt/files/ && ./backup.sh > /opt/files/backup.txt` I am currently managing my backups.

As you can imagine, this directory gets bigger and bigger over time. I now would like to create another script (or cronjob if it works with one command) to delete the oldest `/opt/files/Backup from $(date +"%d.%m.%Y at %H:%M:%S").zip` after 14 days (so that I have 14 recent backups all the time).

It would be great if you could explain your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /opt/files/Backup -name \*.zip -a -mtime +14 -ls
```

If you are satisfied the files being matched are the ones to delete, replace -ls with "-exec rm {} \;"